# Security impact of cheap L2 switches

Tags: network, exploit

What is the importance of firmware in Managed L2 switches? Does using ancient software matter from a security standpoint? Is a Linux 2.6.x firmware easier to hack than a 4.x one? What about outdated eCos? Do those switches really have an attack surface outside the servers (Radius?) and management VLAN? If one only doesVLAN what could possibly go wrong? Could a Zyxel or HP (Linux or eCos) switch with outdated firmware be secure? How would the firmware interface itself with the hardware in this case?

My wired alarm system could run MS-DOS for all I care, it will never get in touch with hostile code (short of physical tampering)... What's the deal with managed L2 switches?

I'm mainly considering integrity (worms, pwnage etc) rather than availability (DoS).

Answer (score 1):

It can matter in some areas, notably how secure the management interfaces are. One potential issue with older switches is that they might support broken or weak encryption, which might allow an attacker to obtain credentials (e.g. the switch might only use a 1024 bit key to secure https).

Similarly, web security has improved over the years, and for switches that provide a web-based administration panel, there may be vulnerabilities in either the web server itself (lighttpd springs to mind, and has CVEs up to 2015: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=lighttpd&search_type=all&cves=on).

A lot of the risks related to these issues can be mitigated by controlling access to the administration interfaces (and the network that provides that access).
In all cases, I would generally tend to think it worthwhile to periodically review known issues and vulnerabilities, to determine what risks may be related to your equipement.

Taking for example the 2.6.7 kernel, a quick, non-scientific check suggests there are two remote exploits to be aware of:

https://www.exploit-db.com/search/?action=search&q=Linux+Kernel+2.6&type=3

I would make sure that those vulnerabilities could be detected, possibly by using or creating appropriate IDS rules. I would also check if there are anyt further remotely exploitable vulnerabilities related to the specific vendor/product.

Local exploits would be the next area I would consider, to understand the risk profile (for example, it may be that local exploits are enough of a concern you will want to prevent humans having access to your equipment, and instead write some kind of script to execute specified actions (or even look at using something like [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/)).

Generally, I think this is a case of first understanding what the actual risks are, and then determining what mitigations exist. This is the same process irrespective of the age of the software.

But do keep in mind the other comments and answers here, which also take into consideration the difference between 'old and working fine' and 'new, possibly safe, but not working'.

Comment: So, is it safe to say that with no servers enabled a Switch with a 2.6.7 kernel is as secure as a newer Gen one? Because that's what the one I'm eyeing runs. It's got a couple of updates, but never a kernel one, which is now 10 years old. Does the ancient Linux not do anything risky in this case? Is it not as bad as running it on a computer provided only VLAN tagging is used?

Comment: SSH is just the same. Encryption did not change. You can still connect safely with SSH or not safely with telnet, just as you can with new ones. There's is a good tendency now: telnet is disabled by default on many new devices. Also, HTTP and HTTPS are identical to the ones years ago, no difference here either - just a matter of choice.

Comment: Yeah, but ssh software gets updated, because it interfaces itself with hostile code/individuals. Now... A dumb switch has no firmware, and you never hear of vulnerabilities there, but what does the Managed one's firmware do other than tagging packets? Does it switch them? Or does the dumb hardware do it?

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that it isn't always about function alone - it is also about how much confidence you can have that the hardware's function are being used as you intended. I might be able to cause traffic to go to places it shouldn't, for example, by using the hardware's functions for my own purposes. This is a bit like how the canonical CSRF example (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) involves abusing legitimate functionality to do evil things (like changing DNS servers or other aspects of a service/config).

Answer (score 1):

The outdated switch is likely vulnerable to various security issues. However, you could still run applications securely on top of it, if you design the application to consider the network untrusted. What this means is that if you keep the endpoints (devices and applications) up to date, and you always use secure connections between the devices (encryption), then it wouldn't really matter if the attacker pwned your switches, as the applications running on it never relied on the network for security anyway.

Comment: So it could be considered a server with lots of ports... The Linux portion DOES switch packets, it doesn't just tag them and allow you to load the management interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a Zyxel or HP switch with outdated firmware can be secure.

It's more about bugs in versions rather than how old the software is.

There are many such ancient versions that are still secure and very stable, while new ones are vulnerable and bugged. As for many things, the increase in complexity increases the number of possible problems, bugs and security problems.

If you have a known to be good version of the outdated firmware you're fine. As a practical example, if you have an old switch that was patched from firmware version 1.00 to 1.01 (that being the only official firmware update) it's way more likely to be secure compared to a new one that was updated from 2.00 to 2.01 then 2.10 than 2.25 (and will probably get a lot more patching).

As a matter of fact, I have many of these switches in my network and I can say hands down that the older ones are actually more secure while the very new ones have to be patched relatively often because otherwise they will have big problems, up to as big as failing to correctly function (I had brand new HP recently where an integer value limitation of a counter caused all the ports to be stuck in the current state - fixed by firmware update).

Comment: Could it not mean that the one with just an update has been abandoned? We're talking about cheap SMB stuff here.

Comment: Not too likely. Those old type switches have been on the market for years and their problems have been most likely fixed at that time. It's important to have the last update of their time, though.